# How to pass basic authentication in rest service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, rest, basic-authentication

I have a REST web service that requires a basic authentication to consume its data. I am consuming it in AngularJS.

The way I am doing it is as follows:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:9200/persons/_search?_source=Gender', {
       headers: {
           withCredentials: true, 
            headers:{ 'Authorization':  'Basic ' + btoa("admin" + ":" + "admin")}

       }
   }).
        then(function(response) {
            ctrl.json = response.data;

        });       
}]);
```

But the error that I am having in the console is:

> Request header field headers is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Can someone help to resolve this issue? Note that I have tested it on postman, and it works fine, returning me all data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue, you have to allow Cross-origin requests from your server

Comment: I have allowed. But the issues persists. Any alternatives ?

Comment: how did u allow it?

Comment: http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, X-User"

I have added the above lines in the configuration files.